# :silent makes my vim go blank

Tags: command-line, external-command, terminal

When I used `:silent` to run a terminal command in the background, my vim screen goes blank, until I navigate through my code, at which point each line I move to reappears.

What gives?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This works as designed, and is documented under `:help :silent`:

> ```
>       ":silent" will also avoid the hit-enter prompt.  When
>       using this for an external command, this may cause the
>       screen to be messed up.  Use |CTRL-L| to clean it up
>       then.
> ```

You can also use the `:redraw` command.

Comment: I found I needed to use `redraw!` - without the bang it was like I'd done nothing

Answer (score 0):

For me, I found out that I couldn't use *redraw* to chain a command like this:

```
:!command | redraw
```

I tried with and without '!' i.e. 'redraw' or 'redraw!' with no luck : I always had to hit Ctrl-L to get my screen back.

I found a solution to this [here](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/vim-shell-commands-silence) and I did this instead:

```
:call system('command')
```

No need to call *redraw*.

For info, I was trying to send tmux commands to another pane from vim. Now my command, that I run when saving my buffer, looks like this:

```
:w | call system('tmux send-keys -t 1 "glow foo.md" Enter')
```

This obviously needs some more scripting and error checking, but you get the idea.